# Dramatic performance decrease when switching to parallel mode

Tags: r, windows-10, doparallel

I am trying to use parallel mode with R on Windows10 / AMD Ryzen 9 proc.

Unfortunately, I am encountering strange behaviors.

One of them is the following: when computing the square of a matrix with increasing dimension, performance drops significantly when the dimension reaches 17, *in parallel mode only*.

I know that there is an overhead to use parallel mode vs sequential mode.
But why is this overhead "normal" below 17, and why does it become so dramatic starting ay 17 ?

Here is the piece of code that demonstrates it:

```
library("tidyverse")

library("parallel")
library("doParallel")
library("foreach")
library("rbenchmark")


f <- function(n) {
  M <- matrix(c(1:(n*n)),n,n)
  res <- M %*% M
  return(norm(res))
}

g <- function(n,m) {
  if (m=="PAR") {
    res <- sum(foreach(i=1:10,.combine="c",.export="f") %dopar% f(n))
  } else {
    res <- sum(foreach(i=1:10,.combine="c") %do% f(n))
  }
  cat("m=",m,", n=",n, " res=",res,"\n",sep="")
}

num_cores <- round(0.5*detectCores())
cat("Setting up the parallel execution cluster on",num_cores,"cores ... ")
my_cluster <- makeCluster(num_cores)
registerDoParallel(my_cluster)
cat("done.\n")

res <- foreach (i=1:20, .combine=rbind) %do%
  mutate(benchmark(g(i,"SEQ"),
            g(i,"PAR"),
            replications=10,
            columns=c("test","replications","elapsed")),
         i=i)

gg <- ggplot(res) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10") +
  geom_line(aes(x=i,y=elapsed,color=test),size=1.2)

print(gg)
```

Here is the output of this code, in logarithmic scale.

[performance result of running function f() in sequence or in parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4BRu.png)

Why does matrix multiplication crashes performance when executed in parallel mode, beyaond dimension 17 ?

Thanks for your help !

CF

Comment: I cannot replicate this on Ubuntu 18.04 with AMD Ruyzen 7 1700 and R 3.6.3. Could you add the result of `sessionInfo()` to your post so we now what R / package versions you use? This issue may be windows specific though.

Comment: Hello, here is the sessionInfo():

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your message ! it just gave me the idea to try a more recent version of R (4.0.2) ... and that solved the problem !!  In any case, here is the sessionInfo() of the configuration that has the problem, which remains when I switch back to R 3.5.3:

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rbenchmark_1.0.0     doParallel_1.0.14    iterators_1.0.11     foreach_1.5.1       
 [5] forcats_0.4.0        stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_0.8.0.1        purrr_0.3.2         
 [9] readr_1.3.1          tidyr_0.8.3          tibble_2.1.1         ggplot2_3.1.1       
[13] tidyverse_1.2.1      RevoUtils_11.0.3     RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.1     compiler_3.5.3   plyr_1.8.4      
 [6] tools_3.5.3      digest_0.6.18    jsonlite_1.5     lubridate_1.7.4  gtable_0.3.0    
[11] nlme_3.1-137     lattice_0.20-38  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.4      cli_1.1.0       
[16] rstudioapi_0.10  haven_2.1.0      xfun_0.6         withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0      
[21] httr_1.4.0       generics_0.0.2   hms_0.4.2        grid_3.5.3       tidyselect_0.2.5
[26] glue_1.3.1       R6_2.3.0         readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.4     magrittr_1.5    
[31] codetools_0.2-16 scales_1.0.0     backports_1.1.4  rvest_0.3.3      assertthat_0.2.1
[36] colorspace_1.4-1 labeling_0.3     tinytex_0.12     stringi_1.4.3    lazyeval_0.2.2  
[41] munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.2      crayon_1.3.4
```